# sort particular column values according to specific column python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

On applying group by on 4 columns of a dataframe using below code :

```
df = df_week.groupby(['Week/Year', 'host', 'table_type', 'table_name']).size()
```

I got data in this form:

```
Week/Year        host        table_type       table_name
31/2017          rb          abc              qrst              10
31/2017          gb          def              abcd              17
31/2017          rb          abc              lmno              8
32/2017          rb          abc              qrst              7
32/2017          gb          def              abcd              1
32/2017          rb          def              lmno              5
32/2017          rb          abc              tuvw              20
33/2017          gb          abc              qrst              19
33/2017          rb          def              lmno              21
```

Now i want to sort the calculated count in last column according to the week/year column i.e in the group of 31/2017 all the values in the count column should be sorted.

For eg:

expected output is :

```
Week/Year        host        table_type       table_name
31/2017          gb          def              abcd              17
31/2017          rb          abc              qrst              10
31/2017          rb          abc              lmno              8
32/2017          rb          abc              tuvw              20
32/2017          rb          abc              qrst              7
32/2017          rb          def              lmno              5
32/2017          gb          def              abcd              1
33/2017          rb          def              lmno              21
33/2017          gb          abc              qrst              19
```

Comment: Have you tried sort_values? Save your grouped df as df1 for ex and then df1.sort_values('Week/Year').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following code, you can sort in ascending order by `Week/year` column and descending order by `size` column.

```python
import pandas as pd

df = df.groupby(['Week/Year', 'host', 'table_type', 'table_name']).size().to_frame('size').reset_index()
df.sort_values(['Week/Year', 'size'], ascending=[True, False])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your data as a `Series` object, sort on the values, then the index:

```
df.sort_values(ascending = False).sort_index(level = 'Week/Year')
```